# SQL Case Statement (or something else) to create multiple columns based on a condition

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I am using SQLite. Imagine I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
Product_ID Product_Price Product_Quantity   Product_Quality
1                    100               10           5
1                   -120               15           8
2                     50               10           4
2                    -50               20           6
```

Where positive numbers indicate sales and negatives indicate purchases. I want to have a query where I can see the average of the values based on if they are sales or purchases (so based on if Product price >0 or <0). So the values I want returned to me are:

> `Avg_sales_quantity: 10`
>
> `Avg_purchase_quantity: 17.5`
>
> `Avg_sales_quality: 4.5`
>
> `Avg_purchase_quality: 7`

I tried using a Case statement but I don't know how to have a Case statement that creates multiple columns. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A CASE statement can return only a single column not multiple columns. You'll need to write multiple CASE statements to get the required columns

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification

Comment: Can you provide your desired output which may help to answer your query.

Comment: The output I want would only have one row with the four columns I specified ad with those values. Imagine I had more rows in the original dataset

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation below :

```
with recursive tab( Product_ID, Product_Price, Product_Quantity, Product_Quality) as
(
 select 1, 100,10,5 union all
 select 1,-120,15,8 union all
 select 2,  50,10,4 union all
 select 2, -50,20,6
)
select avg( case when coalesce(Product_Price,0) > 0 then Product_Quantity end )
       as Avg_sales_quantity,
       avg( case when coalesce(Product_Price,0) < 0 then Product_Quantity end )
       as Avg_purchase_quantity,       
       avg( case when coalesce(Product_Price,0) > 0 then Product_Quality end )
       as Avg_sales_quality,
       avg( case when coalesce(Product_Price,0) < 0 then Product_Quality end )
       as Avg_purchase_quality
  from tab;

  Avg_sales_quantity    Avg_purchase_quantity   Avg_sales_quality   Avg_purchase_quality
  10                    17.5                    4.5                 7
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=e259955b98d601e1642d6e0350567120)</kbd>

Comment: Would I have to do it for all rows if I had 1000 rows for example?

Comment: @memokerobi definitely no, do not confuse columns with rows. i.e. for every case for row numbers, you get 4 columns above as average.

Comment: yes I want 4 columns as my result but if I had 1000 rows would I have to write 1000 select statements with union all?

Comment: @memokerobi of course no :) that just represents your sample data, normally you don't have this part( with recursive tab() as ( ... ) ) but you already have your table's (tab) data in your database.